# Why I am getting this error(AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names')?

Tags: python, python-2.7, hashlib

So far there seems to be only one question regarding this error in the entire forum..

When running any pyo example in E-Pyo through Python 2.7.11 I get this error:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyolib\_core.py", line 22, in <module>
    import random, os, sys, inspect, tempfile
  File "C:\Python27\lib\random.py", line 49, in <module>
    import hashlib as _hashlib
  File "C:\Python27\lib\hashlib.py", line 138, in <module>
    _hashlib.openssl_md_meth_names)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'openssl_md_meth_names'
```

I installed python 2.7.11 just for E-Pyo, I had already been using 3.42 so I believe the error may stem from this.

Some search led me to check the sys path in relation to hashlib:

```
   import sys
   print sys.path
   import _hashlib
   print _hashlib.__file__
   import hashlib
   print hashlib.__file__
```

output:

```
['', 'C:\\Program Files\\Csound6_x64\\bin', 'C:\\Python27', 'C:\\Python27\\pytho
n27.zip', 'C:\\Python27\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python27\\lib', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\plat-wi
n', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages']

C:\Python27\DLLs\_hashlib.pyd
C:\Python27\lib\hashlib.pyc
```

I am not quite sure how to interpret this as I am fairly new to programming..

So, the question is, how can I correct this error?

Thank you!

I am on an ACER F550L Intel Core i7-4500U 1.8 GHZ running Windows

Comment: i have a similar issue except it's... AttributeError: module 'arcpy' has no attribute 'BooleanAnd_ia'. @Questionsabound did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
setup.py install
```

Instead of:

```
python setup.py install
```